# Histogram and Statistics not showing in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, statistics, histogram

I've been trying to calculate the histogram and statistics in ArcGIS Pro through Symbology. I've tried seeing the histogram of "create chart" (but it shows different results from Symbology's histogram), and I have also tried using the "calculate statistics" function on Geoprocessing, but it didn't work. How do I proceed?

[image: Red arrow = the function that I want to use; blue lines = the different results]